# how to delete extra labels in bar plot in Latex?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

How to delete extra labels on X axis: `53, 113, 241.`

I spent plenty of time to do it reading manuals on pgfplots and others...

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

...

\begin{tikzpicture}    
   \begin{axis}[title = Performance comparison of our approach vs. Synopsys for 100-bit inputs,
      width=320,
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
      symbolic x coords={19, 53, 113, 241},
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=south},
      legend columns=-1,
      ymax=1200,
      ybar,
      ylabel={Frequency, MHz},
      xlabel={Moduli},
      nodes near coords,
      every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize}
   ]    
     \addplot coordinates {(19,1162) (53,840) (113,819) (241, 862)};   
     \addplot coordinates {(19,662) (53,746) (113,892) (241, 869)};
     \addplot coordinates {(19,564) (53,854) (113,634) (241, 789)};

     \legend{Synopsys, group, bits}
   \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! You seem to be looking for `xtick=data`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[title = Performance comparison of our approach vs.\ Synopsys for 100-bit inputs,
    width=320,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    symbolic x coords={19, 53, 113, 241},
    xtick=data,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=south},
    legend columns=-1,
    ymax=1200,
    ybar,
    ylabel={Frequency, MHz},
    xlabel={Moduli},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]

\addplot coordinates {(19,1162) (53,840) (113,819) (241, 862)};

\addplot coordinates {(19,662) (53,746) (113,892) (241, 869)};

\addplot coordinates {(19,564) (53,854) (113,634) (241, 789)};

\legend{Synopsys, group, bits}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you will usually get much earlier an answer if you provide us with complete minimal working examples which start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled.

Comment: thank you so much!!! You are the God of Latex))